# Excel pivotcharts to webpage

Tags: javascript, excel, charts, html, kibana

I have few excel pivot bar charts and trend analysis graphs. 
Is there a way to display the excel charts on a webpage, without losing the interaction capabilities? 
So, from the excel users can filer,dig deeper etc.
Can i do the same using some other technologies?
Any technology stack is welcome, open source more so. 
I am trying out Kibana right now, but doesn't seem to have all the capabilities as excel does.

[Update] I tried out Google charts, but that sends data to Google server, which cannot be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like to post an answer to my own question, But http://www.highcharts.com/  is my favorite now. Very easy to use charts and quite zingy. 
Minor point : it's not free for commercial usage, so we will have to get a license for it.